# relative v absolute path?

Tags: html, url

What would the relative path of the following url be?

http://domain.com/wp-content/themes/themename/images/breadcrumb_sep.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

/wp-content/themes/themename/images/breadcrumb%5Fsep.png

"relative" to the host.... I think that is what you mean, that is the common meaning.

Answer (score 5):

Relative to the root of your domain? `/wp-content/themes/themename/images/breadcrumb%5Fsep.png`

Relative to the Themes folder? `themename/images/breadcrumb%5Fsep.png`

It depends on where you are actually placing the link. Pretty much just remove the common parts of the path.

Comment: @martin clayton, oops. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on where it's being called from hence the term relative, it's relative to where it's being called from.

If you're in a sub-folder of your root other than wp-content then the relative path would be

`../wp-content/themes/themename/images/breadcrumb%F5sep.png`

Answer (score 0):

In the source html file could be relative to some path defined by base href, see:

```
<head>
<base href="http://domain.com/wp-content/themes/themename/images" />
</head>
```

then

```
<a href="breadcrumb%5Fsep.png">text</a>
```

Anyway, please be more precise with your question to get better answers :)